# RPM %files section: how to handle special characters in filenames?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How do I handle filenames that contain special characters within an rpm's %files section?

I'm building an RPM but I have a few filenames that contain special characters.  I'm not the developer so I do not control the filenames checked into the source code repository.

My example %files section is below:

```
 %files -f files.serviceX.list
 %defattr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser,-)
```

My files.serviceX.list contains:

```
%config(noreplace) %attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /etc/serviceX/serviceX.conf
%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /opt/serviceX/tests/runtests.sh
%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /opt/serviceX/tests/configtests.sh
%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /opt/serviceX/tests/badinput.sh
%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /opt/serviceX/tests/#1 escaping.sh
%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /opt/serviceX/tests/#2 bad filenames.sh
```

The only workaround I've found so far is to list the directory which contains the filenames using special characters in files.serviceX.list:

```
%config(noreplace) %attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /etc/serviceX/serviceX.conf
%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /opt/serviceX/tests/
```

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: I should add that quoting the bad filename does not work and rpmbuild still complains:
    `%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) "/opt/serviceX/tests/#1 escaping.sh"`

Comment: did you try escaping the space using `\ ` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard and avoid the problem:

```
%attr(-,serviceXuser,serviceXuser) /opt/serviceX/tests/*.sh
```